# Visual Studio 2022 gives "internal error in the C# compiler" in Debug Mode

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

On trying to put a watch the value of any object in Debug mode in Visual Studio 2022, I get "internal error in the C# compiler" instead of the actual value.

Many posts in StackOverflow suggest checking this option in Visual Studio IDE. Tools-> Options > debugging > enable Use Managed Compatibility Mode

This option is not available in Visual Studio 2022.

Comment: Please post the code that causes the error.

Comment: Its not any specific code. When I put a watch on a value at the Controller level in MVC instead of a value in the watch item I get the value "Internal error in the C# Compiler"

Comment: [Known problem](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/VS-2022-Internal-error-in-the-c-compile/1602726?space=8&q=vs2022+internal+error+in+the+C%23+compiler), fix is coming.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because there appears to be nothing that a denizen of SO can do to resolve; it's for Microsoft to fix

Comment: Thank you @Hans Pasant

Comment: Even after updating to the latest version if you are still getting this e doing so will fix it.  1) Delete bin and obj folder 2) rebuild solution and now it works.

Comment: I encounter this periodically with VS 2022 v 17.3.0 (post MS-fix). It appears to occur when I have a project targeting .netstandard debugging against code running under .net48.  Clearing /bin and /obj from my .netstandard project folder(s) make no difference.