# Visual Studio does not show any locals: Internal error in the C# compiler

Tags: c#, autocad

I am developing a plugin for AutoCAD 2022, and I stuck with a problem: when I try to evaluate variables and objects inside this while loop during debug, I see nothing.

What did I do wrong?

```
public void ProcessSurfaces(HooverSpace.Map.WorkSpace ws, ShellForEntity mapEntity)
{
    g3.Vector2d moveBoxVect = new g3.Vector2d(0, 0); //offset relative previos by AxisX

    SchemaForUnwraping schema = new SchemaForUnwraping(g);
    listPlanedComponents = new List<Component>();
    int f = 0;

    AxisAlignedBox3d bbox3d = Map.GeomCenterMap();

    while (true)
    {
        if (!schema.IsThereMoreComponents(components_g))
            break;

        f++;
        Subgraph next_g = new Subgraph(schema.GetNextComponent(components_g));
        //                                        if (f != 1)
        //                                           continue;
        listPlanedComponents.Add(new Component());
        int numComponent = listPlanedComponents.Count - 1;
        listPlanedComponents[numComponent].Init();
        List<(Point3d, Point3d)> pointTo3d = new List<(Point3d, Point3d)>(); 
        ...
    }
}
```

Some functions are from external module Satsuma. It is lib for work with graphs.

If anyone knows how to fix this, I would greatly appreciate help.

I am using ReSharper, it shows near the object/variable its value. And inside the while loop, it shows only “Internal error in the C# compiler”.
But outside the loop, everything is normal. I checked different while loop and everything was normal.

Comment: Which variables specifically? where is `g` and `components_g` defined? Do any calls made in the loop have to be awaited?

Comment: Any variable I checked, even int variable `f`. `g` and `g_components` are properties of class in which the `ProcessSurfaces` function is. And there are no awaited calls in this loop.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70397734/visual-studio-2022-gives-internal-error-in-the-c-sharp-compiler-in-debug-mode